# Parameterized differential equation limit solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the differential equation:
$$x'(t)=\beta\left(-\frac{x}{1-\sin(t)/2}+\frac{2-x}{1+\sin(t)}  \right) $$
I would like to prove that when $\beta\to 0$ then the solution converges to $x(t)= 2$ as suggested by [numerical results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VX6M.png).

Answer (score 0):

As $\beta \rightarrow 0$, $x'(t) \rightarrow 0$, so $x(t) = c$ for some constant $c$, which depends on some initial condition which has to be given.

**Edit:**

The ODE is of the form $x'(t)+P(t)x(t)+Q(t)=0$ with $P(t) = \beta \left( \frac{4+\sin(t)}{(1+\sin(t))(2-\sin(t))}\right), Q(t) = -\beta\frac{2}{1+\sin(t)}$, which are continuous for $t \neq -\pi/2 + 2\pi k$. Therefore a unique solution must exist in the neighborhood of *any* initial condition, so for a finite $\beta$ we can always find a solution passing through any given point $(t_0,x_0), t_0 \neq -\pi/2 + 2\pi k$.

If your assumption is correct, then as $\beta \rightarrow 0$, and taking $x_0 \neq 2$ we should have a spike with diverging derivative at $t_0$, which means that $x(t)$ diverges, because $P(t), Q(t)$ and $\beta$ are bounded in the neighborhood of $t_0$.

Do the numerical results give spikes with diverging $x$ near $t_0$?

Comment: Actually it does not seem to depend on the initial condition. I solved it numerically for some values of x(0) from 0 to 100 and it always converges to x=2 when $\beta$ is very small.

Comment: There is an erratum: $\beta$ is also in $Q$.

Comment: Numerical results for different $\beta$ and different $x_0$ give a spike round $3\pi/2$.
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/feHpK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9o1j.png

Comment: but not around $t_0$? Also, according to this image it looks line the limiting function is not $x(2)=2$, but a piecewise-constant function, which would make more sense with the arguments made above.

Comment: It does not diverges around $t=0$. Yes, the limit solutions seems to be $x=x_0, t\in[0:3\pi/2]$ and $x=2, t\in]3\pi/2, \infty]$.

Comment: Numerical results for $\beta=0.01$ and different values of $x_0$ : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar0iO.png